# unattended-upgrades vs cron-apt on a server

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

What are the advantages of unattended-updates over cron-apt and vice versa?

Basically I want a fully automatic upgrade process in the night:

- install all updates (even non-security)
- reboot if necessary
- it would be good also to trigger a scheduled maintenance in our icinga on before reboots

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Comment: `unattended-upgrades` is about [an order of magnitude more popular](https://qa.debian.org/popcon-graph.php?packages=cron-apt+unattended-upgrades+apticron&show_vote=on&want_legend=on&want_ticks=on&from_date=&to_date=&hlght_date=&date_fmt=%25Y-%25m&beenhere=1) than `cron-apt`, at least within Debian, even though it seems to be slightly younger. Also, `unattended-upgrades` is [documented in the Debian Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.regular-upgrades.html), whereas `cron-apt` is not.

Answer (score 3):

## cron-apt

Cron-apt only downloads new packages by default. This can be useful if you have a strongly customized system. (for more details, see source [1])

## unattended-upgrades

apt includes support for running an unattended upgrade script; Ubuntu includes this with the ''unattended-upgrade'' package which handles both security and non-security updates. The frequency of updates can be changed by setting the variable `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "x";` where x is the number of days, e.g. `"1"`

Check if the value is already set somewhere with:

```
sudo grep Periodic::Unat /etc/apt -rH
```

if not, add the line in a the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

This is the recommended way to do unattended upgrades in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

*(`-plow` is the short form of `--priority=low`.
That is, show all questions of 'low' priority or higher.)*

**Automatic upgrades can break your system**, so be aware, that you should only install this on systems where a failiure is not fatal to any means.

[1] Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` worked!!